# How to read Solaris 11 drive using an OmniOS server

Tags: hard-drive, solaris-11, omnios

I have a drive which was originally in a Solaris 11 server. The Solaris 11 server is not available. I would like to access the data using the OmniOS server. Is this possible?

I have read there is a lack of compatibility between Solaris 11 ZFS and OmniOS ZFS.

I have also read there is something called v28 pool which can be used.

How do you read a Solaris 11 drive without Solaris 11?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Was this drive in ZFS pool? If yes, how many other drives was in pool? If no did you try using UFS as filesystem?

Comment: Server is ZFS and drive is ZFS. Only one drive is in pool. Tried inserting Solaris 11 drive in the OmniOS server and ran `zpool import archive_CJ1` Returned: cannot import 'archive_CJ1' : pool is formatted using an unsupported zfs version.